# What compiler does Android use and can I change it?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, compiler-construction

When I compile an Android project within Eclipse, it doesn't generate any Ant scripts or anything, so I assume it's using the Eclipse compiler to generate the .class files, and using `dx` to translate those into .dex.  So that's fine, and I'm aware that the Eclipse compiler is different from `javac` and can't be changed.

But when I use `android` to generate a `build.xml` file, I see that it references other Ant files, and eventually I am able to track down the actual invocation to `javac`.  So I have a few questions about this.

1. I'm an Ant newbie.  Does the `<javac>` Ant command correspond to the `javac` referenced by my `JAVA_HOME` env variable?  Or is it something else?
2. When you use the 'Export Application' option in Eclipse, does it still use the Eclipse compiler?  Will I always be forced to use a different compiler in Ant vs. in Eclipse?
3. Can I specify any compiler I want if I alter the `build.xml` file and change the "compile" target?

I don't really care that much what compiler I'm using, I'm just curious.  The main thing I'm after is to make sure that I'm using a modern compiler and I can expect all the usual optimizations (e.g. the interning of string literals).  **Am I correct in assuming this?**

P.S.  Speaking of optimizations, does `dx` do anything more fancy than simply translating one bytecode to another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer question 1, Yes it must be using the one referenced by JAVA_HOME. The evidence being: I can successfully build projects with Ant, my JAVA_HOME is set to c:\dev\tools\JDK6_20. My path includes c:\dev\tools\JDK6_20\bin.

I temporarily set JAVA_HOME to the non existant c:\dev\tools\JDK6_201. When I try an ANt build, I get:

BUILD FAILED
C:\dev\projects\Eclipse\AndroidWorkspace\MapProject48\build.xml:390: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\dev\tools\JRE\6_20_64bit"

I don't know where it gets the last line from, I guess it must be my JRE as it appears in the registry.

I think that in answer to your **bold** question : the compiler is as modern as the javac in your JDK

Answer (score 2):

With regard to your question about dx, it's not the end of the process.  When the application is installed on the device, a lot of local lookups are done to create an optimized dex (ODEX) file unique to the run environment of that device.

Comment: Interesting!  I think I remember Dan Bornstein mentioning that in his Google I/O Dalvik talk.  Do you know any details about what it does?

Comment: There's a lot of documentation in the Android source tree: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/dalvik.git;a=tree;f=docs;h=b0d3023109f548626cce1a9a586c95e82fb012ac;hb=HEAD .  Try "dex-format.html" and "dexopt.html" (the former looks better if you grab it and the corresponding CSS file and view them locally).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you are getting at. However, Android uses a modified form of Java called Dalvik.

Dalvik is register based, which is better for mobile devices.

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29)

Comment: The source files are first compiled to java byte code.  As far as I know that's done with whatever JDK you installed, not by eclipse itself.  The java byte code is then converted to Dalvik byte code by android sdk tools (probably dx)

Comment: It's usual practice to set environment variables of %JAVA_HOME% ant %ANT_HOME% and add %JAVA_HOME%\bin and %ANT_HOME%\bin to your path. As far as I know there's no separate 'javac' for Eclipse. It's just an IDE that supports many languages. You set %JAVA_HOME% to your JDK not the JRE

Comment: @NickT:  Wrong.  Eclipse has its own compiler.  See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061654/what-is-the-difference-between-javac-and-the-eclipse-compiler).

Comment: @Neil, Thank you for correcting me. So I guess it must keep up to date with the JDK features when additions like generics are added?

Comment: Yes, it currently has compliance with the Java Language Specification up to 1.6, and you can configure it to use an older specification (down to 1.3) if need be.