# What is the purpose of Java JDK to Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, java

I've just installed Eclipse, after i installed the java JDK.
The Getting Started guide (in Eclipse) says i should reference my JDK installation in Window>Preferences>Java>Installed **JREs**, but that a JRE would also work.

> Select the Java > Installed JREs preference page to display the installed Java Runtime Environments. Confirm that a JRE has been detected. By default, the JRE used to run the workbench will be used to build and run Java programs. It should appear with a checkmark in the list of installed JREs. We recommend that you use a Java SDK instead of a JRE. An SDK is designed for development and contains the source code for the Java library, easing debugging.

There was already a JRE set up there (not a JDK), so i did nothing and tried to compile a Hello World (just to see what would happen). To my surprise, it compiled!

I searched a little bit and it looks like this works because Eclipse has a built-in Java Compiler. I tried debugging using the same eclipse set up, and it was also successful.

So, what is the difference between setting a JDK and JRE there? Why is it important to download the JDK, since in my default configuration Eclipse doesn't seem to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of tools that come with the JDK that don't come with the JRE - JConsole (http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html) springs to mind. This for example can help you understand & monitor the memory usage of your application and so on. Either way if you head into unfamiliar territory, I highly recommend you follow the Eclipse suggestion and use the JDK!

Comment: I see. I think i'll even take a look at this JConsole, seems useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Probably the main difference is you get the source to all of the Java runtime libraries (with the JDK) which can be a big help. I always use the JDKs for that reason.

Also if you are debugging, this will allow you to meaningfully step into Java runtime libraries.

Comment: I don't know if that is the *main* difference, but it is a big one. Couldn't live without the source attachment.

Comment: Oh, thanks! That's true... i had always used eclipse with a jre (just like it came), then i could never step into the Java libraries... (always got an error i didn't really know why - i didn't even know java was open-source...). I guessed i've just improved my debugging a lot. Great!

Comment: This is probably the main difference for a majority of users.

Answer (score 1):

JDK is equipped with different helpful tools, as DotMasta mentioned. Eclipse's "version" of JDK is called [JDT](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/overview.php). Apart from range of shipped tools, there are also differences between `javac` and Eclipse built-in compiler `ecj`, so check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061654/what-is-the-difference-between-javac-and-the-eclipse-compiler) to see the comparison. One of the most important differences is that `javac` is strict, i.e. with `ecj` you can create a class file even in case of errors in code, which is perfectly suitable for testing phase, but not for launch :)

Answer (score 0):

JDK contains software development tools which are used to compile and run the Java program.

- Plenty of classes and methods in standard jdk library
- Javac java compiler

Diffrences and why you will need this?

JDK includes the JVM, standard class libraries, and several other tools that a developer needs in order to create a Java program. 
JRE includes the JVM, as the JRE provides some standard libraries and the JVM which can be used to execute a Java program.

You can even look there: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit