# Interface binding in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, interface, compilation

I have the following code in Eclipse(Helios)/STS which runs and prints console output when doing a Run As> Java Application, in spite of obvious compilation issues

```
public interface ITest{
    String func();
}

public static class Test implements ITest{
    void printFunc(){
        System.out.println("Inside Test Function");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Test test = new Test();
    test.printFunc();
}
```

Can anyone pinpoint the reasoning behind this Eclipse functioning.

Note: Doing a javac externally obviously fails to compile.

Comment: I tried. eclipse shows usual method not implemented error.

Comment: Yes. The Eclipse compiler does show an error. But the code still  manages to "run" through Run-As> Java Application. Hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse's Java compiler is designed to cope with flaky, non-compiling code. It will add whatever stuff is necessary to the code to get it to compile.

See this question [What is the difference between javac and the Eclipse compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3061654/116509)

Answer (score 1):

It might have been that you have coded the class **successfully** before the errors. Eclipse auto-compiles your file while you are coding. Just then, you happen to have errors.. then you decide to run as Java Application, Eclipse will run the **most recent** compiled class.

I tried your code, implemented the necessary methods to remove the errors, then removed it again to put back the errors.. sure enough, it printed out `"Inside Test Function"`. I also tried commenting out `System.out.println("Inside Test Function");` and it still printed out.

In another try, I created another class, added your code, then run (**without implementing the errors to avoid auto-compiling**), then it printed out an error..

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
Exception in thread "main"
```

Comment: How'd you get a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main` error. Did you put the exact same code in the new class you created. I tried to recreate the scenario like you said, but my experience is different as stated. Everytime I save the jave file , I get a matching console response and not a 'cached' one (eg. the commenting out Sysout part). Just want to check if you are _building_ the file after saving it?'