# How to get the Java compiler error messages when calling it as an external process?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, javac

I want to make my own small java editor, but I don't know, whats the best way to compile a java class, and get the return messages like errors.

I tryed it so, but I can not get further...

```
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("javac");
    try
    {
        Process process = builder.start();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: If I were having trouble making code that calls the java compiler, I would not take up IDE development...

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus that looks like *if I can't help it, I won't do it* =\

Comment: For learning purpose, everything is a valid task. The question is only if the task fits the current knowledge :D

Comment: Very true, but even the most basic IDE features are actually extremely complex to code yourself. It's like writing your own XML parser. It's something you are just bound to get wrong, even more so if you are not a very experienced programmer. So all you will get from that is frustration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javac pointing to the java file which will generate one .class file, then you have to tart another process to run the class file (if it has a main method) and consume it's output to show it on your editor.

You might also use Eclipse Compiler for Java which is a jar file that gives you an API for compiling on the fly java [What is the difference between javac and the Eclipse compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061654/what-is-the-difference-between-javac-and-the-eclipse-compiler)

But why are you doing this in the first place ?

Comment: Must I only import the jar and if yes where I can get the jar File and a documentation about the api?

Comment: Yes, you can look here http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_api_compile.htm and here http://blog.deepakazad.com/2010/05/ecj-eclipse-java-compiler.html

Comment: But it's actually rather a little complicated. It's something someone of at least 1year java experience guy will find it challenging, and for what ?

Answer (score 0):

[Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) documentation offers getErrorStream() and getOutputStream() methods. Read that streams, but from separate threads.