# How can I find the ecj version in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I'm having a small issue where some java classes compiled in eclipse are slightly different from the classes compiled by a standalone ecj (from the same source code). How can I find the version of ecj that is being used by eclipse? (I'm assuming that's where the difference is)

Comment: Did you compile them with `javac`? I've come across a similar post a while ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061654/what-is-the-difference-between-javac-and-the-eclipse-compiler

Comment: @GGrec In eclipse I just compiled normally, it uses ecj afaik. For the standalone compilation, I specifically used ecj. There should be no javac involved.

Comment: Huh. Interesting. I'm curious to see a relevant answer. Are you decompiling your classes by any chance? How do you notice the difference?

Comment: @GGrec rsync :) But I guess I could compare the disassembled code too, I'll look into that

Comment: Yeah javap -c shows some small differences, such as pop vs astore_1. Anyway I might have an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of ecj is specified by the version of JDT that you are using.  Go to Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Plugins.  Look for the org.eclipse.jdt.core version.

I'm guessing that this will answer your question as posed here, but probably won't solve your problem as to *why* the classes are different.

You should also realize that if you use different options for compilation, then your class files may be slightly different.  I forget offhand how to specify options in ecj (I think you pass in a properties file).  But inside of Eclipse, the options are specified by merging the workspace and the project options.  I'd guess that your differences come from an options mismatch rather than a version mismatch (just a guess though).

Comment: Yeah I got a similar answer on irc, I was about to post it. Here it's more like "Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Plugins". The version I got is 3.8.3.xx-20130703-1700-e42-RELEASE which seems to imply ecj 3.8.3.

Comment: I think the differences are due to optimization changes or sometimes bug fixes. It could also possibly be due to different options, but in order to find out, I should use the same ecj version first anyway :)

Comment: I see you have groovy-eclipse installed, which uses a patched version of the JDT core plugin.  If you want to use the same ecj, then make sure to use the one from groovy-eclipse.