# Compile errors in IntelliJ but not in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

I'm switching to IntelliJ IDEA from Eclipse and i get compile errors in IntelliJ, but not in eclipse.

```
public class TestClass<K, V extends Comparable<V>> {

private K key;
private V value;

public void someMethod() {
    if (this.value instanceof String) {
        String stringValue = (String) this.value;
        // some code
    }
}
}
```

(dont blame me for that code, it's legacy code and not mine)

In eclipse everything is fine, in intellij it is marked as an error which says "inconvertible type, cannot cast V to java.lang.String".

For both i use my standard MacOS X JDK (1.6.0_65).

It's not only with String, it's with every type/class (i have some other concurrents of this)

Why do i get these errors in intellij but not in eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

Java's `String` class is final, there is no way that your `this.value` inherits from it. You should use `.toString()` or `String.valueOf()` to avoid the casting.

You see the phenomenon because Eclipse compiler is different from javac (that used by default in IntelliJ, but you can change that). Eclipse compiler is more permitting. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061654/what-is-the-difference-between-javac-and-the-eclipse-compiler) for more information.

Comment: ``this.value``is not inheriting from ``String``. i updated my question for better understanding

Comment: That's why you can not cast it to `String`. You can only assume that it implements `Comparable`.

Comment: But why do i get this error only in IntelliJ but not in eclipse?

Comment: Ok thank you. So i changed the compiler, it compiles without errors, but still shows me those errors in the editor ?

Comment: Yes, IntelliJ is trying to be intelligent and notifies you about bad java code :)

Comment: I guess there is no way to turn that off? ;)