# Preinstalled eclipse with java 1.7

Tags: java, eclipse

For a short programming project, I have to install an `eclipse with jdk 1.7` on my clients laptop. However, I have insufficient installation rights and my client cannot hand me over more rights.

At the moment, I have downloaded `eclipse kepler` which has a `jre 1.6` preinstalled, which is not enough to make my application, which uses the `crawler4J` libary runnable. Is it possible to get an `eclipse` with `jdk 1.7` preinstalled, which just can be unzipped to make it runnable?

I appreciate your answers!

**UPDATE**

I get a match for the execution environment:

[image]

However, for 1.7 I get no match:

[image]

Comment: Which JDK see at `Java > Installed JREs > Execution Environments` in Eclipse Kepler?

Comment: @herry Pls have a look at my update!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for update.

I looked for preinstalled eclipse on [eclipse donwload page](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/). Kepler is already supported Java 7, but these IDE doesn't contains JDK. I think JDK 1.6 was installed before than Kepler on your clients computer. So, its need to install.

[This page](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-with-java7.htm) help to change your project to 1.7. Meanwhile its good to know [Eclipse has own compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3061680/1047582).