# Eclipse Build Process

Tags: java, android, eclipse, build

how does eclipse build an application (java/android) while ignoring some errors? because when i generally compile my java class on command line or using ant - i end up getting errors - whereas they can be ignored in build process for eclipse.

For example,***non static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context*** is compilation error i get on command line when i try to build an application through ant - but eclipse java compiler can set this as a warning and allow the process to complete.

Can anyone help me understand this process?

Comment: Ant has javac command which is differ then eclipse compiler as it has own compiler. Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061654/what-is-the-difference-between-javac-and-the-eclipse-compiler/3061685

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse contains its own compiler (the Eclipse Compiler for Java, ecj) that is able to report compilation problems to the IDE and even, in some cases, partially compile classes when it can limit the "damage" caused by an error (such as to a single method).