# compiler differences eclipse vs. oracle: cast error incompatible types

Tags: java, eclipse

This can be compiled by Eclipse but not by javac:

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> violations = new HashSet<>();
Set<ConstraintViolation<Class1>> validateClass1 = null;
violations.addAll((Set<? extends ConstraintViolation<Object>>) validateClass1);
```

javac says:

```
error: incompatible types: Set<ConstraintViolation<Class1>> 
       cannot be converted to Set<? extends ConstraintViolation<Object>>
```

The produced code of Eclipse is executable.

Comment: I get an error in Eclipse too. What version are you using?

Comment: Eclipse is using javac aswell. You might use a different version of java for eclipse.

Comment: @LuudvanKeulen Eclipse has it's own compiler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061654/what-is-the-difference-between-javac-and-the-eclipse-compiler

Comment: @JornVernee Wow I was not aware of that. You do have to specify a java location though. Guess that's only for running it.

Comment: What are you asking? Which one is right? Eclipse is wrong: that is a `Set<? extends ConstraintViolation<?>>`, not a `Set<? extends ConstraintViolation<Object>>`. But also, you can't add a `ConstraintViolation<?>` to a `Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>>`.