# Gradle: How to compile Java by eclipse ECJ (JDT core) by running Gradle 4.1 task

Tags: eclipse, gradle, compiler-errors, javac, ecj

I have a project that can be build well by **eclipse (ECJ)** But **Oracle javac** can't build it (some reasons like in link: [the different of ecj and javac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061654/what-is-the-difference-between-javac-and-the-eclipse-compiler)). 
I would like moving from eclipse to build by Gradle, in order to Jenkins can run Gradle script. But Gradle always use javac to compile. I used the plugins 'eclipse, eclipse-wtp' or library, dependency of jdt to config gradle use ECJ like that but it still don't use ECJ to compile:

```
compileJava{   
    options.forkOptions.with {
    executable = 'java'
    jvmArgs = ['-classpath','_mylibary_jdt_jar']
    }
}
```

The problem: I don't know the way (no document, some ways but expired with old gradle or incorrect) gradle 4.1 run task with Eclipse Compiler (ECJ) to compile the classes I expected.

> Note : This error when I built by javac: [incompatible type with javac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46168970/incompatible-types-listobject-cannot-be-converted-to-list-extends-serializa/46169299?noredirect=1#comment79313735_46169299) . I want to run well by task gradle with ECJ.

Comment: This answer appears to be open (unanswered). Did @Taivaan 's answer cover your question? If yes, please consider accepting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to the gradle build script worked for me:

```
configurations {
    ecj
}
dependencies {
    ecj 'org.eclipse.jdt:ecj:3.25.0'
}

compileJava {
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.with {
    executable = 'java'
    jvmArgs = ['-classpath', project.configurations.ecj.asPath, 'org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.Main', '-nowarn']
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right, I also have read the code of the plugin ECJ and understand the way done. https://github.com/xinthink/gradle-ecj

Comment: but where to add this snippet? More information could be useful.