# about Eclipse for Java

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, ide

If eclipse has a compiler (see [Wikipedia article on IDEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), third line), itself why do I have to download the jdk for compiling `.java` files? Doesn't eclipse convert my file to bytecode?

Comment: You might want to read [what a compiler is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between javac and the Eclipse compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061654/what-is-the-difference-between-javac-and-the-eclipse-compiler)

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse has its own compiler and it can work with JRE only. JRE is needed because Eclipse itself is run with java. However if we have JDK installed we can see Java platform class sources during develepment. Also Eclipse's Maven plugin uses JDK compiler.

Comment: The JRE is also needed to actually run the compiled program. So you'd need it even if Eclipse weren't written in Java (unless Eclipse also implemented its own JVM and Java standard library, which it doesn't).