# Eclipse runs the program, same does not work when ran through command prompt

Tags: java, eclipse

I was going through some basic java concepts. I was looking into methods and trying to verify this error

```
"MethodSignature.java:10: error: method m1(String) is already defined in class MethodSignature
        public static void m1(String s)"
```

The above error appears when I run from command prompt. But when running through eclipse, although it shows error, program prints the desired strings. I do not get any error as stated above in case of command prompt.

Why there is a difference in execution in Eclipse and command prompt?

As in command prompt, I am not able to run the program itself because the error should stop me.  I was expecting the same in Eclipse.

Here is my simple program.

```
public static void m1(String s)
{
    System.out.println(s);
}

public static void m1(String s)
{
    System.out.println(s);
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{       
    m1("call one");

    m1("call two");



}
```

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061654/what-is-the-difference-between-javac-and-the-eclipse-compiler gives you more detail on your question.

Comment: Thanks @NavneetRabadiya

Answer (score 0):

You must be running a previously compiled class, you cannot declare `m1` twice. However, eclipse does have its' own compiler (ecj); and it is possible to run code ignoring errors (in which case it removes the invalid code for you).