# Why does Java allow var<T>?

Tags: java, eclipse

Let's take a look at these declarations:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {{add("hi");}};
System.out.println(list.get(0));
```

and

```
var list = new ArrayList<String>() {{add("hi");}};
System.out.println(list.get(0));
```

Both are identical, thanks to type inference. But I was shocked to see these compile as well:

```
var<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {{add("hi");}};
System.out.println(list.get(0));
```

and

```
var<Integer> list = new ArrayList<String>() {{add("hi");}};
System.out.println(list.get(0));
```

The same byte code is generated by all of the above approaches. I was expecting `var<T>` to fail but it doesn't. I have searched for this in the JLS and JVMS but didn't find anything related to this behaviour.

Why does Java think `var<T>` is valid? Backwards compatibility?

EDIT: See comments.

Comment: This doesn't compile for me in Intellij IDEA 2020.1.1, also using JDK 14

Comment: I think it is IDE specific. Working on STS 4.

Comment: Okay, it's not related to Java. It's specific to eclipse. Java has problems with it but strangely eclipse doesn't.

Comment: eclipse uses its own compiler. Assume that the JDK `javac` is the golden standard.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061654/what-is-the-difference-between-javac-and-the-eclipse-compiler

Comment: Watch out for the *double brace initializer*. It's bad.

Comment: There is a bug report for this [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=560999)