# Do Eclipse and the OS use the same "javac"?

Tags: java, eclipse, javac

Javac on my command line

```
$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_151
```

whereas on Eclipse, it looks like this

I wonder whether Eclipse and my OS (Mac) use the same javac?

[image]

Comment: they don't. Eclipse uses its own compiler. See this thread for instance : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061654/what-is-the-difference-between-javac-and-the-eclipse-compiler

Comment: Note: Eclipse may also be using a different `java` as well as its own compiler. The most recent versions of Eclipse include a Java 15 that Eclipse uses (and requires at least Java 11)